# Draggable model but disable it on input field?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I'm trying to implement a draggable object both using a directive for JavaScript and the simpler, `draggable="true"` attribute. (Testing both, obviously using only one at a time).

My overly simplified code is something like this:

```
    <div draggable="true>
       <input>
    </div>
    
    <div [draggable]>
       <input>
    </div>
```

The dragging works fine using both the directive and the attribute, but I want to disable the drag when clicking on the input field. Right now when I try to highlight the input field by dragging, it instead drags the entire model instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onfocus` evevnt and disable the `draggable` by `setAttribute("draggable", false)`:

```js
       function disbaleDrag(e) {
            e.closest("div").setAttribute("draggable", false) 
        }
```

```html
    <div draggable="true" style="border:1px red solid; width:200px; height:100px;" >
        <input onfocus="disbaleDrag(this)" type="text">
    </div>
```